# How to hotkey the brightness settings

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys, brightness, backlight

I want to hotkey certain often used brightness settings under ctrl+ F7 through F10.
I can already change it with the therminal.
To be able to do this I ran the following command

```
chmod 666 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

After that I was able to change it with

```
echo <value I want> > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

(You might need to change "intel_backlight" to whatever vendor you have.)

After that worked I went to "System Settings -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts" and added a custom shortcut with the following values

Name = lowest brightness

Command = echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

and I set it run with ctrl + F7 
but when I press ctrl + F7 nothing happens (

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

outputs the same value it had before pressing ctrl + F7)

Making a little script that executes these commands and setting that to a hotkey also didn't work (executing it with a therminal did work)

How do I fix this?

ps. my grub file has one a little alteration to make the brightness function keys work.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0"
```

but I can't use the function keys to reach the desired values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I'm an idiot
I forgot the shortcuts don't support bash script
I changed my command value to

```
bash -c "echo &#60;value I want&#62; > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"
```

That worked.

ooh well. this might still be useful to for some other people.